# Where to start on interface development?

Tags: iphone, graphics, interface, usability

I maintain an app for my business and am pretty much self-taught on code. I understand all of the structural code, and everything is perfectly usable. My problems is with the overall boringness of the looks. Everything is stock iOS from buttons to backgrounds to pinstripes on the list view. Does anyone have any guides or tutorials they used to take a stock iOS app's look to something like the Piictu app? (I'm not looking for something that impressive but in between that and stock iOS; and I'm open to a full app re-start.)

Comment: Try to show your source code to some professional programmer (or make your application open-source) to get useful feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all of controls can be customized with the view properties. and also there are lots of fully customized controls published with its source code.

Answer (score 0):

With iOS5 there is a lot more scope now for customisation of UIKit elements. However, where this is not custom enough for your design then you would need to write your own controls rather than only using Apple'. There are a few good ADC videos on this.